# Is there a way to divide multi index dataframe with a singled indexed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division, multi-index

I have a multi-index series that looks like:

```
                        Value1    Value2
Month  Group  Type
 02      A     Blue       2         3
               Red        5         4
         B     Blue       4         7
               Red        8         12

 03      A     Blue       9         22
               Red        44         5
         B     Blue       45         34
               Red        22         14
```

I would like to divide this dataframe with this other here:

```
        Value
Month     
 02       2
 03       10
```

And divide based on month index. The result should be like that:

```
                        Value1    Value2
Month  Group  Type
 02      A     Blue       1         1.5
               Red        2.5         2
         B     Blue       2         3.5
               Red        4         6

 03      A     Blue       0.9         2.2
               Red        4.4         0.5
         B     Blue       4.5         3.4
               Red        2.2         1.4
```

I have tried df.div(df2, level = 0), but get a dataframe with NaN's

Answer (score 2):

You need select column `Value` for divide by `Series` and add `axis=0` for compare by index:

```
df = df.div(df2['Value'], level=0, axis=0)
print (df)
                  Value1  Value2
Month Group Type                
2     A     Blue     1.0     1.5
            Red      2.5     2.0
      B     Blue     2.0     3.5
            Red      4.0     6.0
3     A     Blue     0.9     2.2
            Red      4.4     0.5
      B     Blue     4.5     3.4
            Red      2.2     1.4
```